# Lifting of Commuting Maps of Vector Bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Assume that we have a vector bundle $\mathcal{F}$ over $\mathbb{P}^d(\mathbb{C})$ that is generated by global sections. Let $\pi \colon \mathcal{O}^n \to \mathcal{F}$ be the associated map that is surjective on global sections. Assume that we are given two maps $f, g \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}}(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{F}(1))$ and assume that they commute in the sense that $f(1) \circ g - g(1) \circ f = 0$ as a morphism between $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}(2)$. We would like to know, whether the following question has been studied: Does there exist commuting (in the same sense) maps $F,G \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}}(\mathcal{O}^n,\mathcal{O}(1)^n)$, such that $\pi \circ F = f \circ \pi$ and $\pi \circ G = g \circ \pi$.

Thanks ahead

Comment: If you want this for all pairs $f,g$, then the least you must have is $\pi$ surjects onto global sections of $\mathcal{F}(1)$. A sufficient condition would be the above and if $K$ is the kernel of $\pi$, then $K(2)$ has no global sections. This is far too strong of course.

Comment: Let us assume that for now. It is not such a far-fetched assumption in our setting.